# SSH agent not autostarting anymore after upgrade to Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, autostart, ssh-agent

I upgraded from Kubuntu* 20.04 to 22.04.  Now ssh-agent is not automatically started anymore upon boot.
To my understanding, ssh-agent is supposed to be started by the desktop environment (i.e. without need to add something in .bashrc, .profile, etc.).  Where/how is this done by KDE and what do I need to do to re-enable it?

I already found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58503/how-is-ssh-agent-being-autostarted) which mentions `Xsession.options`.  However, "use-ssh-agent" is already listed there, apparently without effect.

All other questions around the topic that I found so far mention adding something in .bashrc, .profile or the like.  However, I'd like to avoid that (it was working without this before the upgrade, so I guess it should be possible to make it work again).

---

<sup>* I realised that it is actually not an original Kubuntu but Ubuntu on which I later installed kubuntu-desktop.  Not sure if this changes things.</sup>

Comment: I just went through this not long ago. I recall having some issues. Have you tried `sudo systemctl enable ssh` and then rebooting to see if it worked?

Comment: @KGIII I think I already tried this earlier.  Just in case, I tried again now, but it didn't work :(

Comment: As a workaround, I now put `eval $(ssh-agent)` in my `.profile`, but I would still like to know how I can restore the default behaviour from before the Ubuntu upgrade, which didn't need any user configuration.